# how to convert a pattern like 'mg-mg-mg-mg-mg....' with only one mg using regular expression or IDQ

Tags: regex, informatica

Im trying to convert the below pattern 
'mg-mg-mg-mg-mg...' and so on
to only mg in my output

i tried using IDQ transformationsbut could not succeed
So can someone please help me with the regular expression may be ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In an Expression Transformation, you could use a combination of `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()`.  Something like this:

```
SUBSTR(portName, 0, INSTR(portName, '-'))
```

This will return all text before the first `-` in `mg-mg-mg-mg`

You could also try experimenting with `REG_EXTRACT()` or `RTRIM()`

Comment: Actually i will have to compare all the substrings from the string and if they are same then only replace it with one substring, and the mg's are not fixed so how many times should i compare .. basically there should be a generalsd rule for it